# How to get rows of Pandas Dataframe where the column value starts with any of given characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas Dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "acc", "bcc"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output of the above code:

```
    col1
0   aaa
1   bbb
2   ccc
3   ddd
4   abb
5   bcc
```

I need to get the rows where the column value starts with - say - either "a" or "c". After the filtering, the result should look as the following:

```
    col1
0   aaa
1   ccc
2   abb
```

How can I achieve this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for `a` and `c`

```
df = df[df["col1"].str.match('^[ac]')]
```

You can include as many letters in the square brackets that you need to match on.

```
df = df[df["col1"].str.match('^[abcdefg]')]
```

Comment: This won't match only `"a"` etc. rows due to the following `.+` part.

Comment: @BrendanA How do we solve the same problem if I had a list i.e. ml = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "acc", "bcc"] instead of dataframe?

Comment: @edn@edn I updated my answer with a different solution...please check if it's viable. :)

Comment: Something like this`df[df["col1"].str.match('^(aaa|bbb|ccc)')]`. Note that I also made a couple edits to the regex in the original Q as well!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
filtered = df[df['col1'].str.startswith('a') | df['col1'].str.startswith('c')]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
  col1
0  aaa
2  ccc
4  acc
```

Edit: as [@Mustafa Aydın](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9332187/mustafa-ayd%c4%b1n) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70916689/how-to-get-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-where-the-column-value-starts-with-any-of-gi/70916715#comment125367793_70916715), you can pass a tuple to `.str.startswith`:`

```
df[df['col1'].str.startswith(('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'acc', 'bcc'))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my actual use case, potential characters are not limited to "a" and "c". It is maybe ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "e", "g"]. Is it somehow possible to use a list related function instead of having too many ORs for each character?

Comment: Yes, in that case, Brendan's answer would probably work well. :)

Comment: I totally agree. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = df.loc[df.col1.str.startswith(('a','c'))]
Out[11]: 
  col1
0  aaa
2  ccc
4  acc
```